# How do I add a second disk to my zfs root pool

Tags: hard-drive, solaris, zfs

I am trying to add a new disk to my zfs root pool. Here is my current config:

```
# zpool status
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
 scrub: none requested
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool       ONLINE       0     0     0
      c0d0s0    ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
bash-3.00# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rpool/ROOT/s10x_u7wos_08
                      311G   18G  293G   6% /
swap                   14G  384K   14G   1% /etc/svc/volatile
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap1.so.1
                      311G   18G  293G   6% /lib/libc.so.1
swap                   14G   52K   14G   1% /tmp
swap                   14G   40K   14G   1% /var/run
rpool/export          293G   19K  293G   1% /export
rpool/export/home     430G  138G  293G  32% /export/home
rpool                 293G   36K  293G   1% /rpool


# format
Searching for disks...done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0d0 <DEFAULT cyl 60797 alt 2 hd 255 sec 63>
          /pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@0,0
       1. c2d0 <Hitachi-   JK1181YAHL0YK-0001-16777216.>
          /pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,5/ide@1/cmdk@0,0
```

Disk 1 above is the new disk I need to attach to expand my root pool (give /export/home some extra space).

If I try to attach my new disk to the pool

```
# zpool attach -f rpool c0d0s0 c2d0s0
cannot attach c2d0s0 to c0d0s0: new device must be a single disk

# uname -a
SunOS dsol1 5.10 Generic_139556-08 i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
# zpool add rpool c2d0
```

cannot add to 'rpool': root pool can not have multiple vdevs or separate logs

Comment: If any answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot add devices to the root pool (outside mirroring it but this isn't going to help in your case).

What you can do is creating a new zpool with your second disk and relocate /export on it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not `zpool add`, rather than `zpool attach`?

These may help:

http://lildude.co.uk/growing-a-zfs-root-pool

http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2006/12/26/adding-disks-to-zfs-pools/

Answer (score 0):

I expanded the root pool easy:

- Login as root

Make sure the rpool can autoexpand

- zpool set autoexpand=on rpool

Format the disk you want to add as a 'Solaris Root' partition using gdisk

- gdisk /dev/sdx

Make a new partition using option 'n'

Filesystem type code should be 'bf00' for Solaris Root

Option 'w' to write the changes

Find the disk by ID

- ls /dev/disk/by-id

Make note of the partition you just made as the Hard Disk model with '-part1' or some other number appended to the name

Add that partition to the zpool (let's say the disk partition is 'disk-part1)

- zpool add -f rpool /dev/disk/by-id/disk-part1

Verify the pool was expanded

- zpool status
- zfs list

You should be able to see the root has expanded storage now